# How to push a branch only if it differs from master?

Tags: git, git-push, multiple-repositories

## The goal

I would like to push a branch only if it differs from the local master. More specifically, I don't want to push a branch if it points to the same commit as the local master.

## Background

My company has hundreds of git repositories, and we don't use git submodules, so for system-wide cleanups I have a very simple bash script:

```sh
for gitdir in `find ./ -name .git|sort`;
    do 
        workdir=${gitdir%/*}; 
        cd $workdir
        eval "$*"
        cd $BASE_DIR
    done
```

that I run like this:

```sh
./for_each_repo.sh 'git checkout -b <bname> && <some command> && git commit -m <message>''
```

Then I may do some other changes to the repositories.

Finally, I run:

```sh
./for_each_repo.sh 'git push origin <bname>'
```

But his, obviously..., pushes also "empty" branches (i.e. where I just created a branch but did not commit to it).

Comment: Why are there branches with no new commit although your process commits for each branch?

Comment: I may be removing some files that are present only in some of the repositories.

Comment: Fair enough, I suspected something like it, but I didn't want to rely just on a safe guess. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I am aware that is not the smartest approach :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,

```
git for-each-ref --no-merged=master --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads
```

would list all branches with new commits (which aren't yet merged into `master`).

Then, you could link that to your push command

```
git push origin $(git for-each-ref --no-merged=master --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads)
```

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti It's `git branch`'s plumbing counterpart. Quite useful to tweak format, for one thing.